# How to migrate from .NET Smtpclient due to basic auth security issues?

Tags: c#, .net, basic-authentication, smtpclient

I have several applications (web, console, API, library) in .NET Framework 4.8 and in .NET Core that send emails using SmtpClient.

```
 SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
 smtp.Host = smtpServer;
 smtp.Port = smtpPort;
 smtp.EnableSsl = smtpEnableSsl;
 smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUsername, smtpPassword);
 ...
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 ...
 smtp.Send(mail);
```

Google since may 2022, Microsoft since october 2022 have removed the ability to use the basic auth and therefore I have errors when sending. I said Microsoft and Google because they are the main ones but I would like to leave the way open to support others.

I am now trying to replace this posting, perhaps using a library (or I can use Graph and Google API).

Microsoft proposes as solutions (both based on OAuth2):

1. EWS (older, SOAP, eg used by Mailkit library);
2. Microsoft Graph.

Google, on the other hand, proposes:

1. The passage from the account password (`smtpPassword`) to an App Password;
2. OAuth2 (eg used by Mailkit library)

Obviously there are other components, even for a fee, that address the problem (es. MailBee, Rebex).

I believe that today a migration should include Graph for Microsoft and not the App Passwords for Google. Is it right?

I have already carried out a research to understand what are the main solutions but I have not found a predominant one that convinced me.

I would like to know if anyone has already faced the problem and what are the tools to do it. SmtpClient was one for all: now that we can't use it? An implementation for each provider?

**EDIT**:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/deprecation-of-basic-authentication-exchange-online

https://office365itpros.com/2021/09/27/smtp-auth-exception/

> After checking with Microsoft, here’s what will happen:
>
> - If a tenant has never used SMTP AUTH, Microsoft is already actively blocking the protocol by setting the SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled organization-wide control.
> - If a tenant is using SMTP AUTH, Microsoft will not disable the protocol. The presumption is that the organization knows how they use SMTP AUTH and has good business reasons to continue using SMTP AUTH.
> - If a tenant discovers that they need to use SMTP AUTH after Microsoft disables the protocol, they can run the Set-TransportConfig cmdlet to update SmtpClientAuthenticationDisabled to $False. However, the big downside in taking this step is that it enables SMTP AUTH across the entire tenant. A per-mailbox setting is available to allow access to SMTP AUTH that overrides the organization configuration. It's obviously better to limit access to potentially insecure protocols, so it's recommended that you enable the protocol on a per-mailbox basis to restrict access just to the mailboxes which need to use SMTP AUTH.

Comment: When you say "what are the tools to do it", what do you mean exactly?

Comment: You already mentioned the options. What should we tell you now on what basis? You are the one that knows your requirements. If its just sending mails via smtp using OAuth auth then use an implementation for net that supports this. Another pretty good one worth mentioning would be from Rebex.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama SmtpClient is one. Now an implementation for each provider?

Comment: @Ralf Rebex doesn's support Microsoft Graph: https://forum.rebex.net/11127/is-there-any-plans-to-add-support-for-microsoft-graph

Comment: "Microsoft since october 2022 have removed the ability to use the basic auth" - at least for Microsoft, it's not true. They did this for IMAP and POP3 but your case is SMTP. For SMTP, the basic auth is still there. And there is no info they will be changing this any time soon.

Comment: @Alex System administrator disabled the configuration. I read also SMTP. What is your source?

Comment: @Emanuele "I read also SMTP" - sorry, I could not understand what "reading SMTP" means.

Comment: @Alex in your message you wrote SMTP can use basic auth. I read it is the same as IMAP and POP3.

Comment: @Emanuele SMTP can use basic auth. IMAP and POP3 cannot use it any longer. That's the current behavior of Office 365 (which can change soon).

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/basic-authentication-deprecation-in-exchange-online-september/ba-p/3609437

Comment: Ok but it's only delayed.